# Permission Error [13] as Administrator

Tags: python, windows, io, permissions, runtime-error

I just want to write a simple script to automate a task I have to do on a big number of files. The script itself is working fine, it reads the files and changes them, but when I want to write the new data back, I get a permission denied error.

I have already looked at the permissions for the folder and all is fine there, my user has full access, the thing is sitting on my desktop after all... I then tried running cmd.exe as admin but I still get the same error. I've tried different opening modes, like w, w+, r+, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT...

Here's my error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automate.py", line 67, in <module>
    with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test\\first_layer\\1_test.cs'

C:\Users\user\>
```

I'm using python 3.6.3 on Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.15063.
There really should be root on windows...

Thanks for any suggestions! :)

**EDIT::**
As suggested, I tried `_winapi.CreateFile(filename, 0xC0000000, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0)`
and this is what I got (both as user and administrator):

```
>>> _winapi.CreateFile(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\first_layer\1_test.cs", 0xC0000000, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: We need to know whether access is denied or it's a sharing violation. Try `import _winapi;` `_winapi.CreateFile(filename, 0xC0000000, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Seems to be, that access is denied. But how can that be, when I'm executing as admin?